# Prevent div jumps down after loading data above it Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I prevent the `Post` container jumps down after loading data into `ThreadsContainer`? I want it to maintain fixed to the top.

```js
    $('.Loadthreads').on("click",function () {
      $('.threatsContainer').append("<br>lorem<br>lorem<br>lorem<br>lorem<br>lorem<br>lorem<br>lorem<br>lorem<br>lorem<br>lorem");
       });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="threatsContainer"></div>
    <div class="Loadthreads" style="cursor:pointer;">[Load Threads]</a>
    <div class="Post" style="background:red;">[I want to maintain fixed at the top after the data above has loaded]</div>
```

This technique is used on Twitter, when you visit the page of a comment of a thread. the comment remains steady up, while the threads load above it. without moving it.

I was thinking using `scroll:overflow,visble` but nothing...I dont want to use fixed positionning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
    $('.Loadthreads').on("click",function () {
      $('.threatsContainer').append("<br>lorem<br>lorem<br>lorem<br>lorem<br>lorem<br>lorem<br>lorem<br>lorem<br>lorem<br>lorem");
         $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(".Post").offset().top}, 0);
       });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="threatsContainer"></div>
    <div class="Loadthreads" style="cursor:pointer;">[Load Threads]</a>
<div class="Post" style="background:red;">[I want to maintain fixed at the top after the data above has loaded]</div>
    </div>
```

What you can do is scroll to the .Post div after loading the data above it using jQuery. Hope will help you.

Comment: This is a better answer. I would add an animate `0`

Comment: Did you try it, is it working as per your expectation? @joe

Comment: add this line please `.animate({scrollTop: $(".post").offset().top}, 0);`

Comment: Added this line. Please mark as approved if it helped and resolved your problem. Thanks and Good Luck. :) @joe

Comment: Welcome brother. @joe